# Ubuntu php and apache development!

Tags: php, mysql

I heard that Ubuntu has already available for installation packages as well , confirmed and it really is true , just installed that came with **php5.5** , I need **php5.2.17** for installation of vBulletin my , how can I install ?

1. Apache 2.2.21
2. PHP 5.2.17
3. MySQL 5.5.21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install a package in Ubuntu you can easily just run the command

```
sudo apt-get install package-name
```

So for example to install the package apache2 you can use

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

This default installation method will install the latest version of package founded in your repositories.

So in order to install a specific version you should use the command like this:

```
sudo apt-get install package=version-number
```

So for example in case of apache

```
sudo apt-get install apache2=2.2.21-1ubuntu1
```

Same for other packages.

**PS:** Still you may face some problem in dependencies. To solve it you have also to install the same version of dependencies using the same method.

for example in case of apache

```
sudo apt-get install apache2=2.2.21-1ubuntu1 \
                     apache2.2-common=2.2.21-1ubuntu1 \
                     apache2.2-bin=2.2.21-1ubuntu1 \
                     apache2-mpm-worker=2.2.21-1ubuntu1
```